# How to deviate to force:createRecord based on the recordTypeId in a salesforce lightning component?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

I have a ligthning component that is clicked when someone is creating new Corset record on the account page which is using force:recordData and also force:recordEditform
I am trying to deviate to standard salesfroce create record layout by using force:createRecord if the recordTyeId = '0121l000000266T'. I am new to salesforce lightning. Can somebody help me to achieve this.

```
<force:recordData aura:id="CorsetData" recordId="{!v.recordId}" fields="{!v.CorsetFields}" targetFields="{!v.CorsetData}"
                  recordUpdated="{!c.onCorsetUpdated}" mode="EDIT"/>
                  <aura:if isTrue="{!lessthanorequal(10,v.accountData.Age__c)}">

                <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="CorsetEditForm" objectApiName="Corset__c" recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                                          recordTypeId="{!v.recordTypeId}">
                 <aura:if isTrue="{!v.recordTypeId == '0121l000000266T'}">


                  // Planning to use force:createRecord to deviate to the salesfroce standard record creation page
                  if the recordTypeId = '0121l000000266T'
                  // The plan is to make the page stay on this custom input fields for other record Type Ids


                 </aura:if>
                 // Some input fields to be displayed in the edit form
```

Comment: Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: can you please answer my questions regarding your issue.1.when aura if is true happened what you want to do? you want create record or not? if not you want display viewform? what you want in else condition?create record? please refere  http://peterknolle.com/lightning-record-edit-form/

Comment: Oh, So, when aura if is true then I want to redirect to the creation of standard mask layout if the Corset__c .

Comment: So, basically, I am trying to find a way to call the createRecord function in the aura if tag. I hope you understand by what I meant

Comment: any help please !!!

Comment: there is 2 if conditions, you want createrecord  when 1st  if is true or 2nd is true?

Comment: on the first one

Answer (score 0):

i think in your case you have to use lightning:recordform if i understood correctly. for that you need a value for v.recordTypeId, if you had value for recordtype then us below code and lpost your issue if you get

cmp

```
<lightning:notificationsLibrary aura:id="notifLib"/>    
<force:recordData aura:id="CorsetData" recordId="{!v.recordId}" fields="{!v.CorsetFields}" targetFields="{!v.CorsetData}"
              recordUpdated="{!c.onCorsetUpdated}" mode="EDIT"/>
              <aura:if isTrue="{!and(lessthanorequal(10,v.accountData.Age__c),v.recordTypeId == '0121l000000266T')}">
<lightning:recordForm
    recordId="{!v.recordId}"
    objectApiName="Corset__c"
    layoutType="full"
    fields="{!v.CorsetFields}"
    columns="2"
    recordTypeId="{!v.recordTypeId}"
    mode="edit"
   onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}"
   onsubmit="{!c.handllsubmit}"
   /> 
</aura:if>
```

controller.js

```
handllsubmit: function(component, event, helper) {

    event.preventDefault();
    var eventFields = event.getParam("fields"); 
// you can customize if you want
},

handleSuccess: function(component, event, helper) {

    component.find('notifLib').showToast({
                        "variant": "success",
                        "title": "Record Created",
                        "message": "Record ID: " + event.getParam("id")
                    });
}
```